# Is there a way to make an under-sink water filter safe from massive leaks?

Tags: plumbing, water-filtration

I'm looking at under-sink water filters on Amazon, and in the reviews, *every single one of them* has horror stories about the filter exploding and leaking 100's of gallons of water while the owners are gone, leading to $10,000's of damages.  Even the expensive brand-name ones!

**Is there any way to mitigate this risk?** Maybe like a shutoff valve that automatically shuts off when the flow rate is too high, or when the floor of the sink-cabinet gets wet or something.

Comment: A google search did find enough to back up Amazon review warnings.  Would probably try to find different water filter system.

Comment: Sure, have a drain tray below the kitchen sink, and design the plumbing with an orifice that limits flow to the unit to "pint per minute" quantities. Possibly with a pressure tank on the filtered side, so the first few glasses flow freely. It would help to not buy non-approved junk sold direct mail to bypass our safety laws.

Comment: For point-of-use HW I put a rectangular mop bucket under it, with a hole drilled for a barbed fitting, with a hose going into a floor drain. 100% passive. 100% effective. And 100% in the way at all times.

Answer (score 4):

- Install a floor drain in/under the cabinet. Be sure to install a trap primer as well (good place for a greywater trap primer from the sink above.)
- Install a standard "water sensor + electric shutoff valve" most commonly seen
  sold for (clothes) washing machines due to similar tales of woe
  involving burst hoses. It might have a hot side you won't need.
- Install the filter system somewhere else (like the basement, near a sump or floor drain) where it won't cause so much damage if it fails. Run a pipe to where you want the water dispensed.

Answer (score 4):

Several companies make a non-electric device that turns off the water to a filter if it detects a leak. They may go by the name "leak stop valve", "leak protection valve" or "leak detector and shutoff valve".

They generally must be mounted on the floor of your cabinet where water would collect in case of a leak. They contain a sponge-like pellet that will expand if it gets wet. The expansion moves a lever that allows a valve to close. Several replacement pellets usually come with the valve.

This one is made by Express Water.
[image]

Comment: Good idea but if you buy one of these, make sure it's not such a cheap load of crap that it is more likely to break apart than the thing that supposedly might leak onto it.  The "IN/OUT" appendages in the pictured device look to me like they'd be the most fragile and vulnerable element of an entire home's plumbing system.  Unless you bought even crappier hoses to connect it.  The electronic ones are a lot more expensive but they do not add new risk to the system.  They install at the meter, you put detectors wherever, and they shut off the whole house if there's a leak.